# Sacar 2 valores de una consulta

Tags: c#

Resulta que uso un textbox para filtrar una lista ordenada según lo que escribo, entonces, se como sacar el texto de la base de datos pero necesito sacar el id también, que es luego lo que voy a usar cuándo guarde el registro en la base de datos. Os muestro lo que tengo escrito, que además de darme error, sé que está incompleto.

```
private void idSuplementoReserva2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd;
            SqlDataReader lector;
            string sql;
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString);
            AutoCompleteStringCollection coleccion = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            sql = "SELECT idSuplemento, LTRIM(RTRIM(Descripcion)) FROM tbl_Suplemento WHERE Visible = 1";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion);
            conexion.Open();
            lector = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (lector.Read())
                coleccion.Add(lector.GetString(0));
                coleccion.Add(lector.GetString(1));
            conexion.Close();
            idSuplementoReserva2.AutoCompleteCustomSource = coleccion;
            idSuplementoReserva2.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            idSuplementoReserva2.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        }
```

Gracias

Comment: Lo mejor que puedes hacer es sacar los datos filtrados y guardarlos en un **DataTable**, así te traes todos los datos de ese registro incluyendo el **id**.

Comment: ¿Cómo sería el código?

Answer (score 0):

Este código es para el gestor de base de datos SQLite pero es similar, desconozco cual este usando. Este caso es para SQLite

```
    public DataTable MostrarTodosLosClientes()
    {
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        using (SQLiteConnection conexion = Connection)  /*Variable de tipo connection que almacenara los datos de ruta etc*/
        {
            conexion.Open();  /*Aqui abrimos el puerto de conexion entre la bdd y el programa*/
            using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand()) /*Variable de tipo command que hace referencia a un procedimiento almacenado*/
            { 
                command.Connection = conexion;  
                command.CommandText = "select * from Cliente";  /*aqui esta la query que nos trae todos los datos, aquí usted puede filtrar por id si así lo requiere, pero independientemente le traerá todos los datos(columnas) del registro filtrado(s)*/
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SQLiteDataAdapter sQLite = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);  /*Aquí se crea el objeto que almacenara esos datos del registro(s) del table filtrado y le mandamos como parámetro el procedimiento almacenado para que retorne con los datos*/
                sQLite.Fill(data); /*hacemos un llenado(Copy paste) de los registros al DataTable*/
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

De manera similar lo puede hacer para cualquier otro gestor de base de datos, solo es cuestión de buscar las funciones que lo realizan, pero casi que se llaman igual solo que sin el SQLite.

Para accesar al id basta con hacer un foreach para accesar a cada fila del dataTable.

```
foreach(DataRow item in data)
{
   Console.WriteLine(row["id"].ToString()); /*y así para cualquier columna*/
}
```

Comment: He instalado el paquete de nugget Microsoft.Data.Sqllite porque no lo tenía instalado y los comandos "SQLiteConnection", "SQLiteCommand", etc... no me cargan, es decir, no me deja escribirlos como código fuente ¿Eso por qué es?

Gracias